# Isotope appending doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I have a photo gallery powered by Isotope.
Images are requested from external resource on page load and every time a user scrolls to the bottom of the page. New images are to be appended to the current isotope layout. The problem is with **Isotope - it doesn't seem to execute the 'appended' method.**

Searching for a solution on StackExchange and Google revealed I am not the only one having this problem. I have been tinkering with this for past couple of days and tried almost every solution I could find but so far I have not found anything that could fix my problem.

**CodePen**: I have created a CodePen here - http://codepen.io/Writech/pen/pBoEt
**WebPage**: As the custom event 'resizestop' is not working in codepen the same code is found as a webpage here - http://writech.net.ee/sandbox/

To see the problem open the CodePen or WebPage provided above and scroll to the bottom of the page which initiates loading of additional images. Then you see the new images are just appended to the container by jQuery. But they are not appended to the isotope layout instance as they are supposed to.

The problematic part lays in a custom function named isotopeAppend(). This function is called on page load and then the second part of 'if-else' statement is executed. When initialization is done and first images are added to the container then the next time isotopeAppend() is called (it's when user reaches to the bottom of the page) the first part of 'if-else' statement is executed and this is where the problematic Isotope 'appended' method is called.

A code snippet below from problematic javascript code. The results of the ajax request to external resource are applied to the variable **newElems**. When adding an alert('something') or console.log inside the 'appended' callback - nothing happens.

Does the problem lay in Isotope itself or does it have anything to do with my coding error?
I would really like to find a solution for this!

```
var elements = $(newElems).css({ opacity: 1, 'width' : columnWidthVar + 'px' });
$('#photos_section_container').append( elements );

$('#photos_section_container').imagesLoaded(function(){

    $('#photos_section_container').isotope( 'appended', elements, function(){
        hideLoader(function(){
            elements.animate({ opacity: 1 }); 
        });
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the initialization change

```
itemSelector : $('.photos_section_wrap'),
```

to

```
itemSelector : '.photos_section_wrap',
```

I [forked](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJxdw) your pen.

`itemSelector` is used by isotope to filter elements to layout and $() returns array of objects. In result there no elements to layout. If you are interested you may look at the `_getAtoms` method (isotope script) in debug to see what's goinig on.